# GAE - Entities of Kind added to table but not reflected in indexes - Python

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to figure this question for the pass few days but can't seem to find any answer - Basically, I've the same code which works perfectly with a duplicate of the Kind's name modified and registerd in Indexes thereafter I follow the examples given by GAE to "entityname.put()" into ndb, same as what I did with my other Kind's entities.

However, this time the new Kind's datas I "put" are recorded into the table as Kind Entities, viewable under the tab in GAE App overview - 'Datastore Viewer' but are not reflected in the 'Datastore Indexes'

Due to the non-reflected data, I'm actually having trouble deleting the key due to the data not reflected in the Indexes.

I hope someone could advise me on this. Thks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the devserver actually CREATES your indexes as they get queried on your dev.  I think this could happen if you:

1- test using the old Kind
2- change the kind name
3- push it like that.

In this way, since you didn't test your queries with your new kind, the system will never create those indexes

Comment: This definitely looks like it could be the issue. Just a note that the devappserver doesn't actually create the indexes as you need them. Instead it marks that you need them, they don't actually get created until you call appcfg update or appcfg update_indexes.

Comment: yeah that might have been a wording issue @PatrickCostello. I meant the devappserver adds your indexes to datastore-index.xml and then when you push your code to the appengine it adds it. Thx for the clarification :)

Comment: Totally right! I just wanted to make sure anyone who saw this made sure to call update_indexes.