# Why isn't my database filter working with google datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The code below works but if I un-comment the 5th line I get an error

```
public void listByKindandFilterById(String kindName, String sortPropertyName, com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudQuery.Order order,
                       int limit, Scope scope, CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> handler, String Id) {

    Log.d(TAG, Id); // I am definitely getting what I expect and whats in the db
    CloudQuery cq = new CloudQuery(kindName);
    //cq.setFilter(Filter.eq("rideid", Id));
    cq.setSort(sortPropertyName, order);
    cq.setLimit(limit);
    cq.setScope(scope);
    this.list(cq, handler);
}
```

I am new to datastore and just want to recreate the WHERE clause in SQL i.e. SELECT * kindName WHERE rideid = Id

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error I get when I un-comment the line:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
{
"code": 503,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Ridemessage\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"rideid\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"_createdAt\" direction=\"desc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n",
"reason": "backendError"
}
],
"message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Ridemessage\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"rideid\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"_createdAt\" direction=\"desc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n"
}
```

Comment: DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Ridemessage\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"rideid\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"_createdAt\" direction=\"desc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datastore needs an index to be able to serve a query. You can look at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig) to better understand how they work.

Basically, I would suggest, to solve your problem, to push your code to your devserver, and make sure you run THAT query on your devserver. That will update your datastore-indexes.xml, and when you update your application, make sure to run "update indexes". It should work fine. I already explained a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410789/gae-entities-of-kind-added-to-table-but-not-reflected-in-indexes-python)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and now looking at my datastore-indexes.xml file it shows autogenerate was false too. Unfortunately I can't mark you answer right just now as I need to figure out how to run this on a dev server and push to google to confirm everything works - the backend starter seems to be very different from other apps i.e. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-codelab-android bear with me while i figure this out

Comment: Note that the error message does give a suggested entry into the `datastore-indices.xml` which you can add manually.  Still, you usually want unit tests to exercise the datastore accesses, so that the indices can be automatically generated.